# How to do batch Insert with max value + 1 logic for non-id column using Spring Data JPA

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to insert a new row in a table. Primary key is composite, id & sequence. Sequence generating logic is max sequence + 1. For each row of same id, sequence generated by max value of sequence + 1.

So I have achieved this logic by @Query with JPA. But batch insert is not happening. For list of data, need to execute one by one in loop statement.

Please help me to find a solution to achieve batch/bulk insertion.

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (ID, SEQUENCE, NAME) VALUES (:id, ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(SEQUENCE), 0) FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = :id) + 1), :name)", 
nativeQuery = true)
Integer insertTable1(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("name") String name);
```

Looking for option with sequence generator as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can't  avoid the sql generation in loop statement, that's how the batch insertion does behind.

@Transactional, will call the commit right away, so maybe you can try to move it to outer method level, so it will commit once after all the loop are completed.